# Consuming web service in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, windows-phone-7

First of all to note that I am calling link?wsdl web service. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I have created Windows Phone application.

I added a New service reference to the WebService, and it generated all of the classes in a proper way. Next what I did is I wrote the bellow code in order to call web service and get the response.

Just to note two things:

1. SoapUI returns correct value.
2. The same code works on Console Application in Visual Studio 2010 and returns the correct string.

The following is code:

```
namespace testApp
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebService.ServiceClient ws = new WebService.ServiceClient();
        ws.FirstMethodCompleted += new EventHandler<FirstMethodCompletedEventArgs>(ws_getReklamaLinkCompleted);
        ws.getReklamaLinkAsync(param1, param2);


    void ws_FirstMethodCompleted(object sender, WebService.FirstMethodCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error is: " + e.Error);

    }
}
}
```

Well the problem is that this code in Windows Phone Application returns following exception:

```
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://testwebservice.portal.com/",    local:"param1"). Expected elements are <{}param1>,<{}param1>
```

I am struggling with this well over 2 days now. Can anyone tell me why the same code works on Console application and not on Windows Phone application and what could be the solution for it?

What other ways I have to consume the web service?

Comment: Can you post WSDL and Fiddler's capture of the result?

Comment: That is kinda confidential I cannot show a wsdl since it is my clients private data. However I have created a Web service and I can edit it in any way if it is necessary, however I don't think that I have to edit it since it works fine with Android app and with iOS, and I am quite sure that I have some mistake in the code above. Or are there some restrictions in calling the SOAP based web service from windows phone, or there is something I overlooked perhaps?

Comment: If you can replicate it using test service, please do post test service WSDL/Fiddler capture.